# What is the current status of submitted manuscript?

Tags: paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted a manuscript to ASME journal. Now the different status is showing as in the figure below: in the general screen, the status is associate editor assigned. However, in the detail screen, the status is under review.
I wonder that the manuscript now has been sent to the reviewer and is under review, or still with the associate editor?

Comment: I know the journal workflow. I wonder here a different status appeared. Then, what is the manuscript status now: with AE or under review

Comment: It looks like the AE is looking for reviewers or even still doing the preliminary review himself, to decide to which reviewer forward your paper. A long way to go ...

You can always wrote the journal (not the associate editor, just their contact/customer care) the exact same question and bring here their answer.

Answer (score 3):

The associate-editor is the person who is handling your manuscript. He is not the person doing the reviews. The associate editor send some e-mails to some researchers to invite people to review your papers. These reviewers will submit their reviews and then the associate editor will make a decision on your manuscript based on these reviews.  The decision could be something like : accept, reject or need to be revised.

So there is no conflicts between these two status. An associate editor was assigned to handle your paper. Then, "under review" means that the associate editor has already invited some persons to review your paper and that at least one of them has already accepted.  Now, it can take some time before all the reviews are submitted... sometimes weeks or months. Then eventually you will get the result.

Comment: So it means the manuscript has been assigned to at least one reviewer. That is what I want to clear here. Thank you Phil!

Comment: Yes, for some journals, the paper will have the status "with the editor" and then as soon as at least one reviewer accept the invitation to review, the status will turn to "under review".  Then, maybe later, the status will turn to "review completed" and then after that the associate-editor will take a decision on your paper.  The names of these status may vary from one journal to another but that is usually the process. You are welcome ;-)